# math function in javascript exponentiation

Tags: javascript, math, exponentiation

I have some calculation in javascript that includes exponentiation.

Can any of you say why does this sentence return value 1???

```
        alert ((0.03+1)^(271/365)-1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The `^` is actually a [bitwise XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). You're looking for `Math.pow()`:

```
alert(Math.pow((0.03+1), (271/365))-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.pow( (0.03+1), ((271/365)-1) )` will give you a result of `0.9924164970995866`

Comment: I interpreted the original expression differently, with -1 being applied after exponentiation. Then the result would be `0.022188992012574182`. Not sure which of us is correct?

Comment: Hmm, fair point. My assumption was OP intended everything after the caret  to be the part of the exponent. That *does* change things quite a bit though, you are correct!